# Delete any file mentioned in .gitignore

Tags: git, rm

I have the following entries in a `.gitignore` file and I want to remove them. The reason why is because these files are temporary-junk files created during a TeX compilation and I want to be able to remove them.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case if the files entries in your `.gitignore` are not starting with `!` then this one-liner should be fine to you:

```bash
while read -r entry;do rm -rf ${entry}; done < .gitignore
```

Comment: Note that the patterns in `.gitignore` may match files elsewhere than in the current directory.

Comment: I'd suggest to make proper `make clean` rules instead.

Comment: If there is any entry in `.gitignore` that starts with a slash, this will end up removing files from your file system root instead of the checkout directory. So don't do this.

Answer (score 10):

```
git clean -Xdf
```

With capital `-X`, `git clean` *only* removes files that match `.gitignore`.

With `-d`, `git clean` also deletes entire directories that match `.gitignore`.

With `-f`, `git clean` will actually delete things instead of warning you. Be careful though. There might be other things (like personal `direnv` configuration) that are `.gitignored` for other reasons, so be sure it is always understood what this command will do before it is run.

A special thanks to @Kusalananda for sharing `git clean`.

---

As an alternative, if you have, say, a folder for dependencies that includes symlinked directories and you don't want `git clean` to recursively delete everything *inside* those directories, you could use this longer form:

```
git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard --directory | head -c -1 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -r rm -r
```

`git ls-files` with these options lists the same directories as `git clean -Xdn`, but more machine-readable.

`head -c -1` trims the trailing newline byte.

`tr '\n' '\0'` translates all newlines to `NUL`s.

`xargs -0 -r rm -r` deletes the files and directories. `-0` makes `NUL` the delimiter. `-r` causes it to skip empty input (warning: this is a non-portable GNU extension).

Answer (score 6):

```
git clean -X -f -n
```

`git clean -X` will remove any files matching the patterns in `.gitignore`.  The `-n` at the end causes it to not actually remove files, only to dry run, reporting files that *would* have been removed.

Add `-d` to also remove ignored directories.

Without `-X`, it removes untracked files (but not ignored files).

See `git clean --help`.